# Version compatibility of Cesium package with Angular

Tags: angular, cesiumjs, npm-package

I have Angular version 8 application and I use Cesium package version 1.65. I want to use latest features of Cesium related to Google APIs. So, I think I need to use latest version of Cesium.

When I upgrade it directly, I get an error in my build related to Terser.

> ERROR in scripts.e4b2ce7d22c11df96dd5.js from Terser
>
> `Unexpected token: punc (.) [scripts.e4b2ce7d22c11df96dd5.js:5861,86847]

I think it may be angular version compatibility but I did not find anything regarding it in documentation. I've updated my angular version from 8 to 9.

I'm not able to understand which is the minimum version of Cesium required for Google APIs feature, and the minimum angular version for it to build successfully in production.